# Add commit to other pull request in order to follow up on that bug (github cli)

Tags: git, github

I.m trying to follow up on other person bug on github. There is an existing PR with his rough work on that bug, I have more updated solution and want to add commits to that PR (actually, want to rebase his commit and squash them). What will be the way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You can't add commits to someone else's pull request unless you have write access to their repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yust publish your own PR, which means:

- you create a fork of the original repo
- make your own branch
- push to your fork and publish your PR, and reference in the comment the number of the previous PR yours is supposed to replaced.

If your changes are based on the old PR itself, you even can:

- add a second remote '`second`' pointing to the other person fork repo, and fetch that second remote (`git fetch second`)
- create a branch based on the second repo branch where the initial PR was done:

  ```
  git checkout -b myBranch second/oldPRBranch
  ```
- add your commits to it, and push to your fork, from where you will be able to do your own PR (again, referencing in the comment that it is supposed to replace the old one).